# Partitioning array index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to implement a randomized selection algorithm where an array is filled with random numbers and the user selects a location and the program returns the value coinciding with the location in the sorted version of the array without actually sorting the array.

The problem is that the program is giving an Array Index Out of Bounds error and I believe I wrote the randomized partition and swap functions correctly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomizedSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[10];

        // fill array with random numbers between the range of 0-200
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int n = (int)(java.lang.Math.random()*199); 
            arr[i] = n;
        }

        System.out.println("There is an array of 10 elements in the range" +
                            " of 0 - 200. Select a location to view" +
                            " the value.");

        int loc = randomizedSelect(arr, 0, arr.length-1, 5);

        System.out.println(loc);

        System.out.println("The array was:\n" + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static int randomizedSelect(int[] array, int start, int end, int i) {
        if (start==end)
            return array[start];

        int q = randomizedPartition(array, start, end);
        int k = q - start + 1;

        if (i == k)
            return array[q];

        else if (i < k) 
            return randomizedSelect(array, start, q-1, i);
        else 
            return randomizedSelect(array, q+1, end, i-k);      
    }

    public static int randomizedPartition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int pivotIdx = rand.nextInt(end - start + 1) + start;
        int pivot = array[pivotIdx];

        swap(array, array[pivotIdx], array[end]);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        pivotIdx = end;

        int i = start - 1;

        for (int j = start; j <= end-1; j++) {
            if (array[j] <= pivot) {
                i = i + 1;
                swap(array, array[i], array[j]);
            }
        }
        swap(array, array[i+1], array[pivotIdx]);
        return i+1;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the index is out of bounds. My assumption is that when it reaches the last element in the array, there is no element to swap it with. Is this the issue? How can I fix this? I was thinking of just partitioning it into two arrays, but I'd prefer avoiding that.

Comment: You have a lot of indexes and not even one bound checking, this is a disaster factory, specially when using random indexes for arrays.

Comment: Debug your code to easily identify your problem.

Comment: Bounds checking is automatic in java.

Comment: @Marichyasana Do not belive blindly in automatic checking of anything. Stay on the safe side. When indexing `array[i+1]`, `array[j]` or `array[pivotIdx]` automatic bounds checking may verify if values used are between `0` and `array.length`, but **will not** guarantee they are between `start` and `end`...

Answer (score 0):

Your call to swap() is passing the contents of the array at the given index position rather than the index position itself for both i and j. To find this all I needed to do was put print statements in swap()

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
swap(array, array[pivotIdx], array[end]);
swap(array, array[i], array[j]);
swap(array, array[i+1], array[pivotIdx]);
```

with

```
swap(array, pivotIdx, end);
swap(array, i, j);
swap(array, i+1, pivotIdx);
```

Because, when you ask for a swap, you use the index and not the value